# How to unwrap a saw blade?

Tags: uv

I have a problem, I just started with Blender. Couldn't find an answer for it on the internet. I'm trying to UV unwrap a saw blade I modelled yesterday, so I could apply a texture to it.

First, I selected all the outer edges on side a, and side b, and then I marked them as seam, but after unwrapping sides of the blade got cut in half. Also, it had some strange connections, so I had to convert the saw blade to tris.

Unfortunately, I can't find a workaround to my problem. Could you please help me out?

This is close to what I need, but it has to be both sides + edges:
[image: This is close to what I need, but it has to be both sides + edges]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you unwrap, you should be selecting only the edges that you want to be separate in the UV editor as seams (it looks like you selected a whole bunch of unrelated ones).

If I was unwrapping this saw blade, I would select all the perimeter edges around the sharp blade part of the saw on both the front and back and that's it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I'll try it out.